# ColdFusion Executing Queries Parallel (Data not updating)

Tags: coldfusion

I do an update and then I try to get back the updated value of the field of which was updated. The issue however, is I am not getting the updated value, rather the prior value. I know the update works correctly because if I query it shows the returned data. I have tried cftransaction isolation="serializable" but it does not work.

My code is below, is there a way around this or will I have to make 2 AJAX request for simpe issue?

```
<cfquery datasource="#application.datasource#">
UPDATE gt_timesheet
SET
    phaseid=<cfqueryparam value="#form.phase#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">,
    projectid=<cfqueryparam value="#form.project#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
WHERE
    timesheetid=<cfqueryparam value="#form.timesheetid#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="phase" datasource="#application.datasource#">
SELECT status,
(
    SELECT ROUND(sum(time_to_sec(duration))/3600,2)
    FROM gt_timesheet
    WHERE gt_timesheet.phaseid=gt_phases.phaseid
) as billedbillablehours,
(
    SELECT ROUND(sum(time_to_sec(hours))/3600,2)
    FROM gt_services
    WHERE gt_phases.phaseid=gt_services.phaseid
) as billablehours
FROM gt_phases
WHERE phaseid=<cfqueryparam value="#form.phase#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
</cfquery>
```

This is making me go nuts because this language is constantly making tasks that should be simple tedious.

Comment: A) What do you mean "updated value of the field which was updated"? B) What is your database type? It seems like the task has everything to do with SQL and little to do with CF.

Comment: Do you get a different result if you execute  the same queries in a query tool (or similar) in sequence?

Comment: Im sorry all, I am taking over some heavy spaghetti code and it seems I cannot find it and I have already spent too much time trying to debug it. The good news is the field updates the ad news is it lags when I try to get the updated value, I appreciate your help though. I myself prefer structured code so until I can rewrite this application properly I will have to use an alternative; once again thank you for your help.

Comment: It sounds like something else is going on. So Ben's suggestion is a good one, if you get a chance to try it. But I understand you have time constraints. Best of luck with spaghetti code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a CF problem, you have an SQL problem, and I think its the subqueries. First why a subquery and not a join?

Can you confirm that they are 1:1 relationships in the subqueries, because if they are one to many you are just going to get the first match.

I don't know your database schema, but doing it the way you currently are i think the SELECT needs to have the table match based on the form field you have just updated

```
<cfquery name="phase" datasource="#application.datasource#">
SELECT status,
(
    SELECT ROUND(sum(time_to_sec(duration))/3600,2)
    FROM gt_timesheet
    WHERE gt_timesheet.phaseid=<cfqueryparam value="#form.phase#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
) as billedbillablehours,
(
    SELECT ROUND(sum(time_to_sec(hours))/3600,2)
    FROM gt_services
    WHERE gt_services.phaseid=<cfqueryparam value="#form.phase#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
) as billablehours
FROM gt_phases
WHERE phaseid=<cfqueryparam value="#form.phase#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
</cfquery>
```

Hope that gets you somewhere, if not I think you need to explain the database schema more.

Comment: _Re: one-to-many relationship_ Seems like the aggregate in the subqueries would eliminate relationship problems..? Though I agree, JOINs do seem like a possibility here too.

Comment: do your subqueries give you what you expect if you run them separately?

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion does not execute anything in the same request in Parallel unless you use `<cfthread>`

Comment: Its not use cfthread, I am thinking it may be because of subqueries. Nonetheless I am going to have to make 2 separate requests.

Answer (score 1):

How is the duration updated after you run the first Update statement? Does it call a trigger? Possibly that is causing the update of the "duration" field to run after the second query. You could try adding a 1 second sleep after the first query to make sure the second query gets the correct value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, I actually tried that however and that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing something in the update statement. Why don't you re-evaluate the query's once again.